# Problem with webview error of android apk when server is offline

Tags: webview, apk

Well, hello there I am facing a problem with webview of a website.
Let me expand : I have created local server and which is working with webview based android apk, now when my server gets offline it is showing like this, where my website address or ip is visible to everyone. Is there any way to hide this with a blank screen / toaster / generic text anything.

P.S coding is on my android studio.
[Main problem what i am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6st7y.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, I want to hide this message "Web page not available - the web page at http//mysite.com could not be loaded because  net :: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" I just want to hide this message with a blank screen or a toaster when my website's server is offline.

Comment: Please help me anyone!!